# Less percentage not work right

Tags: css, less

I`m trying to get percentage in lesscss file with 2 digits accuracy.
In lesscss file

```
@w: round(((100-((12-5)*3.8))/(12/5))*100);
width: percentage(@w/10000);
```

Compiles to width: 30.580000000000002%;
What I`m doing wrong?

My logic is very simple:
Step 1: Get the "not right" digit 30.580000000000002
Step 2: 30.580000000000002*100 = 3058.0000000000002
Step 3: round(3058.0000000000002) = 3058
Step 4: 3058/10000 = 0.3058
Step 5: percentage(0.3058) = 30.58

Comment: Doing that with floating-point numbers is just asking for trouble. You cannot assume this will work with all numbers, nor is it necessary in the first place. See my answer.

Comment: Try storing `@w/10000` in a variable and passing it to percentage.

Comment: @AlexW Storing it in a variable is not going to change anything as the variable type will either be floating-point (ECMAScript `Number`, probably), or string. If it is LESS client-side, we can safely assume that `@w: round(((100-((12-5)*3.8))/(12/5))*100);
width: percentage(@w/10000);` will be converted to code of the form `variables["w"] = Math.round(((100-((12-5)*3.8))/(12/5))*100);
rule.width = ((variables["w"] / 10000) * 100) + "%";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not considering that floating-point computation is done in binary, where there is no exact representation of 1/10000.  Therefore:

```
/* 30.580000000000002 */
console.log(Math.round(((100 - ((12 - 5) * 3.8))/(12 / 5)) * 100) / 10000 * 100);
```

(It does not matter if LESS uses an ECMAScript implementation like JavaScript, as long as computation is based on [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) double-precision floating-point numbers.)

However, you should not bother about that.

```
width: 30.580000000000002%;
```

is [perfectly Valid CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#percentage-units).

Comment: Yes. You are right. The problem was in /10000. But to my surprize  
`.test{
 @w: round(((100-((12-5)*3.8))/(12/5))*100);
 width: percentage(@w/100)/100;
}`  
Works fine =)

Comment: @GOsha That is because you still do not understand floating-point computation. See the "IEEE-754" link. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `round()` method around the `percentage()` method, like so:

```
@w: round(((100-((12-5)*3.8))/(12/5))*100);
width: round(percentage(@w/10000));
```

Comment: I need to round it with 2 digits accuracy. If I write round around percentage - it will not be so.

Comment: Just do _round(percentage(@w/100)) * 0.01_ then.

Comment: @EdD That does not work (always) as there is no exact representation in binary of 1/100 either. One could use `percentage((…).toFixed(4))`, assuming that arbitrary ECMAScript code could be used in LESS. It could break in certain implementations, though, see the [comp.lang.javascript FAQ](http://jibbering.com/faq/#formatNumber).

Comment: @AlexW `round(…)` will always round to an integer, not the 2 decimal places that the OP wants. I doubt this can be solved in LESS alone.

Comment: @EdD In fact, I doubt that works. [`round(…)` is documented to work on *number* values.](http://lesscss.org/#-operations) `percentage(…)` generates a percentage, essentially a *string* value.

Comment: Edited question to explain my logic

Comment: width: percentage(@w/100)*0.01 compiles to width: 30.580000000000002%  
but width: percentage(@w/100)/100 compiles to width: 30.58%

Comment: @GOsha that is very strange because multiplying by 1/100 and dividing by 100 should be the same operation.

Comment: @AlexW Not in limited-width binary-digit floating-point operations; where there is no exact representation of a number, there are rounding errors. The more operations, the more likely a rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be important when trying to minimize data traffic. These days, [it does not make sense](http://gehrcke.de/2013/02/save-some-css-traffic-round-percentages-with-less/) to send CSS percentages over the wire with more than one or two figures in the [mantissa](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html).

Given the following LESS input:

```
w: 100 %;
w: round(512 * 1%, 2);
w: 2.0 / 3.0 * 100 * 1%;
w: round(2.0 / 3.0 * 100 * 1%, 2);
w: round(0.19%, 2);
w: round(0.19%, 1);
w: round(10000%, 1);
w: round(10000, 1);
```

and corresponding output:

```
w: 100 %;
w: 512%;
w: 66.66666666666666%;
w: 66.67%;
w: 0.19%;
w: 0.2%;
w: 10000%;
w: 10000;
```

we see that `round(percentage, 2)` non-destructively achieves what we want.